# Auto-indent doesn’t work after writing comment in Pycharm/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm, auto-indent

After defining any Python function in Pycharm if I write any comment first, then auto-indent doesn’t work for following statement. I have to manually indent following statement after writing any comment in Python function in Pycharm.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CZOr.jpg)

How to fix this?

Comment: May try - turn off the "Smart indent" option for comments to see if helps?

Comment: I turned off "Smart Indent" option for comments. But still facing the same problem.